# Return strings based on folders in directory

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a code which will look in to a specified directory and return the names of the folders in there. I need them to come in separate strings, instead of in one line, so that I can then use them to create new folders based on those names the code returned.

So far this is what I have:

```
def Lib_Folder():
       my_list = os.listdir('/Users/Tim/Test/Test Library')
       if '.DS_Store' in my_list:
           my_list.remove('.DS_Store')
           return str(my_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'", "")

Library_Folder = '%s' % ( Lib_Folder() )

print Library_Folder
```

and it returns this

```
# Result: testfolder1, testfolder2
```

What I would like it to return is

```
testfolder1
testfolder2
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there's a much easier way to do this. Don't try to manipulate the string that represents the list. Work with the list itself. Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to separate each entry with newlines.

```
def Lib_Folder():
       my_list = os.listdir('/Users/Tim/Test/Test Library')
       if '.DS_Store' in my_list:
           my_list.remove('.DS_Store')
           return "\n".join(my_list)  # Puts each on its own line.

Library_Folder = Lib_Folder()  # The %s thing you were doing is unnecessary.

# Let's check whether it worked!
print(Library_Folder)
# testfolder1
# testfolder2
```

Comment: P.S. Are you sure you want the `return` indented like that? I think it should be one level less indented.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to process the values as is, and not try to process the string representation of a Python list, there are lots of little edge cases if you go that route that will cause problems.

Also, your description mentions only wanting the directories in the target folder, you're not checking for that, you will output the files as well.

And I find this is a preference thing, but I prefer to avoid building up lists in memory if I can avoid it.  It really doesn't matter for a handful of directory names, but it's a habit I like to get into, so this solution shows how to use a generator:

```python
import os
def Lib_Folder():
    target = '/Users/Tim/Test/Test Library'
    for cur in os.listdir(target):
        # Check to see if the current item is a directory
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(target, cur)):
            # Ignore this folder if it exists
            if cur != '.DS_Store':
                # It's a good folder, return it
                yield cur

# Print out each item as it occurs
for cur in Lib_Folder():
    print(cur)

# Or, print them out as one string:
values = "\n".join(Lib_Folder())
print(values)
```